# Do we have ablaut in the Bengali verb system?

Tags: historical-linguistics, indo-aryan

Do we have ablaut in the Bengali verb system?Is it why we have vowel alternation?

Answer (score 4):

If we take *ablaut* to mean the [Indo-European ablaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_ablaut), [we do not see it](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=e1HyCQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA23) in the Bengali verb system. Instead, they can be seen in derivational patterns in loanwords from Sanskrit, e.g. বিজ্ঞান `/biggæn/` "science", but বৈজ্ঞানিক `/boiggænik/` "scientific", where *i* has become the diphthong *oi*.

But Bengali does have *vowel alternations*, e.g. the infinitive কেনা `/kena/` "to buy" becomes in the simple present tense for the 1st person singular কিনি /`kini/` "I buy"]. The `/e/` of the infinitive has become `/i/` before the final `/i/` of the verbal suffix.

This is replicated across the conjugation: before `/i/` and `/e/` in the suffix, the vowel of the root is raised if it is a mid vowel: `/e æ o ɔ/` to `/i e u o/` respectively. This is interpreted as a case of *vowel harmony* or *vowel assimilation* rather than the Indo-European ablaut.

However, a few verb suffixes are low vowels e.g. the second person familiar (তুমি *tumi*) in the present continuous is ছো `/tʃʰo/`, the first person in the future tense is বো `/bo/`, the first person in the simple past tense is লাম `/lam/` and the third person familiar in the simple past tense is লো `/lo/`.

These still trigger vowel raising, because of a diachronic change: all these had an `/i/` before it, as can be seen from the সাধু ভাষার *shadhu bhasha* forms. [For কেনা `/kena/` "to buy"](https://www.banglatangla.com/conjugate.php?verb=%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE) :

> SIMPLE PAST
>
> [সাধু ভাষা *shadhu bhasha* > চলিত ভাষা *cholit bhasha*]
>
> (আমি) কিনিলাম (*kinilam*) > কিনলাম (*kinlam*)
>
> (সে) কিনিল (*kinilo*) > কিনলো (*kinlo*)

Hence the vowel raising in the stem is a trace of the `/i/` that was previously present across all the forms of the simple past. A similar process occurred for the future tense.

There is also a related `/a/` to `/e/` alternation, which occurs only for certain verbs and certain verb forms, and forms the basis of certain conjugation classes. Compare জানা `/dʒana/` "to know" with খাওয়া `/kʰauwa/` "to eat".